# checkbox is checked from the code but jquery cant see it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Im working with asp.net mvc 2 and in my action i put a property to true by default so it will be checked when it writes in the code, its a checkbox.

this generates the following code

```
<input id="BookTalent_BookATalent" class="bookTalent" type="checkbox" value="true" name="BookTalent.BookATalent" checked="checked">
```

now i got a second checkbox "filmPermit" that is unchecked by default, now the way it supose to work is that if both checkboxes are checked nothing changes but if this "filmPermit" checkbox is checked by itself it supose to hide a div.

now the code i got works fine when i dont set the default check on the booktalent checkbox, like if i check the filmpermit checkbox it hide the div, and if the booktalent checkbox is checked it wont hide it. but why does it not work when i set the default to be true "checked" on booktalent checkbox?

this is my jquery for the checking of

```
$('.filmPermit').click(function () {
            $('#filmPermit').toggle(this.checked);

            if (this.checked) {
                if ($('.bookTalent').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#lookingFor').toggle(true);
                } else {
                    $('#lookingFor').toggle(false);
                }

                if ($('.quote').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#lookingFor').toggle(true);
                } else {
                    $('#lookingFor').toggle(false);
                }
            } else {
                $('#lookingFor').toggle(true);
            }
        }).triggerHandler('click');
```

**EDIT:**
this is the code i use for markup

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BookTalent.BookATalent, new { @class = "bookTalent"}) %><label>Book A Talent</label>
        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BookTalent.Quote, new { @class = "quote"}) %><label>Get Quote</label>
        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BookTalent.FilmPermit, new { @class = "filmPermit" }) %><label>Film Permit</label>
```

Comment: could you also add the HTML markup that you are using?

Comment: Well you've got *two* pieces of code controlling the visibility of "lookingFor" ... also, I'd use ".show()" and ".hide()" instead of ".toggle(true)" and ".toggle(false)"

Comment: ok ill try out the show and hide, but the code works the two checkes is because there are some other scenarios aswell but it does not effect the result of the question, why is it not reacting to that the checkbox booktalent is set to checked when it the code is generated? if i choose to not generate it with checked it works like it supose to

Comment: Actually, you could make the code my simpler by replacing the conditionals  with $('#lookingFor').toggle($('.bookTalent').is(':checked'));

Comment: thanks for the tip johnFx ill try it, any ideas about my question?

Comment: I'm working on a theory. Stand by.

Comment: Can you please post the rendered html, instead of the asp.net code?

Comment: Another problem I see is that you are checking $(".bookTalent") instead of $("#BookTalent_BookATalent") the former could return multiple items and might have weird results.

Comment: @Niklas - he did, look at the top of the question.

Comment: @JohnFx - It only has a single <input> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this code is structured, the state of `.bookTalent` is completely irrelevant.  Immediately after checking `.bookTalent` you have the following:

```
if ($('.quote').is(':checked')) {
    $('#lookingFor').toggle(true);
} else {
    $('#lookingFor').toggle(false);
}
```

which overrides whatever was done as a result of the check on `.bookTalent`.  I can't tell you how to fix it because you didn't say anything about what `.quote` is supposed to do.

Comment: quote is a checkbox and its not checked. im pretty sure this is not the problem but give it a shot with your thoughts on it ;)

Comment: it IS the problem.  If `quote` is checked `lookingFor` will always be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working theory.

You are checking `$(".bookTalent").is(':checked')` instead of `$("#BookTalent_BookATalent").is(':checked')`

Selecting on the class could return multiple items and the .is() command will return whether ANY of the selected items are checked.

Try using the more precise format and see if it makes a difference.

BTW: You also have the same problem with `$('.quote').is(':checked')`

Comment: I only got the problem with booktalent checkbox, even if i use the id its not working like it is supose to. the thing that bugs me is that if i uncheck it and check it then its working.

Comment: How about `$('.bookTalent').filter(':checked').doWhatever().end.filter('not(:checked)').doNotWhatever();`